# How to store encryption key on DOTENV file?

Tags: java, dotenv

So I made a program that encrypts a given string ,
The encryption is simple storing `ASCII` characters value from 32 to 126 in DOTENV file , one being a normal string storing values from 32 to 126 and other string storing a shuffled value of the normal string

---

**Given Data is not original data but a sample data**

Data stored in DOTENV file :-

> normalValue = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

> shuffledValue = "GKR6]^|hdv?\Icfs,TBrnt:C0F;p\"SA=U#l .&x<%u4V$7>XgZmq2Ozoi/_Nye[J{LW~1)`YHE-Qk'a!M*}bPj8D(9w5+3@"

---

As you guys can see the data is stored in double quotes because DOTENV dose not support spaces without double quotes  and because  `ASCII` values from 32 to 126 contains double quotes on both list i had to add a back slash as an escape sequence so the string is registered in DOTENV and because of that the program tend to break while encrypting or decrypting , normal words like hello  or even this paragraph

"Linux is a family of open-source Unix-like operating systems based on the Linux kernel, an operating system kernel first released on September 17, 1991, by Linus Torvalds."

works fine , the problem is that when sometimes i use very long text to encrypt it breaks on some letters and its because i cannot store raw data on DOTENV file and get it , i cant seem to find a fix for this as both shuffled and normal string needs to have that , anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not use the term 'encryption' for this trivial scheme, it might mislead somebody into thinking a hacker would need more than about 5 milliseconds to crack this scheme.

Encryption algorithms ordinarily operate on bytes. Your peculiar take operates on characters, but surely the point of what you wrote is to learn something (I sure hope it's not to protect information against those who shouldn't read it, because, oof, this isn't the way), so perhaps it's useful to use the techniques you'd use to store arbitrary bytes in a storage system that is character based and *extremely* limited in which characters it supports (a subset of ASCII is all you get).  There are many systems that work like that: Config files, email, parameters in web URLs, and more.

The solution is base64. This encodes bytes, at a 75% efficiency rate (you need 4 characters to store 3 bytes), as characters in a way that these characters are going to survive just about everything, and work in any configuration environment.

The [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class will take care of the conversions for you. You're in the weird scenario that your encrypted data is in String form (it should be in byte form!), but there's an easy solution to that:

```
byte[] data = theString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String copyOfTheString = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

lets you convert from String to byte[] and vice versa (so that you can then treat the byte[] as the data you need to save, by using Base64 to encode it into a safe string and then storing the safe string).

NB: If this wasn't a learning exercise but you are actually trying to secure information from prying eyes, the basic solution is something like AES256, which is baked into java, and you can find free and open implementations of it with a casual search of the web. Note that it is extremely easy to mess up the scaffolding around the use of such an algorithm: The algorithm is secure (if there is somebody on the planet that can break AES encryption, they can trivially earn hundreds of millions of dollars in a year if they play their cards right), but your particular usage of it may not be.